# Export GMF diagram to ecore file

Tags: emf, eclipse-gmf

I created GMF diagram editor from EMF model using article http://gmfsamples.tuxfamily.org/wiki/doku.php?id=gmf_tutorial1. But I could find possibility to export diagram created in this editor back to EMF(ecore file). Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean with Ecore file? Usually (unless you configured it otherwise) your GMF editor will create two files: One file holding the model, and one holding the notational elements (fonts, node positions, etc.). I think the model file is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I found this files